# How to add colums in excel table dynamically?

Tags: excel

I have a separate sheet where I maintain a list of things, I use it to use in data validation.

Now I want to use the same list as the heading of the columns of my table. Is it possible to do that?

Essentially whenever a new entry is added to the list, a new column gets added and if an entry is deleted from the list, the column gets deleted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will want vba in a worksheet change event.

Comment: With your reputation, you should know by now that asking *'Is it possible...'* is an inappropriate question.

Comment: @Jeeped How come these type of questions are discouraged? Genuine question..

Comment: @designedbyscott, because the only valid response is either *Yes* or *No*. It's not a programming question and is much more likely to be a phishing attempt to get someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @designedbyscott - [Here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916836/how-to-create-data-structure-in-excel). How can you answer that one?

Comment: I have updated the title, to be more directed with the question. Sorry for the previous title.

Comment: @Jeeped: Sometimes it happens that people come from different domain of expertise, in many cases it might not be an attempt to get the code, but just to get a pointer in the right direction. In my case, i dont use excel on a day to day basis, so for me the problem is to get to know if it is even doable in excel, second step is how to do it, should I use formula/macro/vba. I am not trying to justify the question or the title, just making a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) into the entire row you want your column headings to be (where "SourceColumn" is the column you want to transpose into the new sheet):

```
=IF(TRANSPOSE(SourceColumn)=0,"",TRANSPOSE(SourceColumn))
```

A slightly more efficient, though not fully automatic method, would be to enter into your headings:

```
=OFFSET(SourceColumn[firstRecord],COLUMN()-i,0)
```

Where SourceColumn[firstRecord] is the first record of your source data and "i" is the column number of where your headings will start. then you drag to the right and cut it off when you start getting 0s. When a new record is added to SourceColumn, you'll have to manually drag the formula into the new heading.